# What is this ground cover plant?

Tags: identification

[image]

It's about 2-3 inches tall and is slowly taking over the world. Bugleweed? It's mowed when the grass gets long, so maybe it doesn't get tall enough to flower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugleweed or Ajuga reptans.  This might be a cultivar or this could be the fall coloring.

[Ajuga reptans](https://www.thespruce.com/ajuga-or-bugleweed-plants-2132213)

Possibly Ajuga reptans atropurpureum?

Comment: Mine is ordinary Ajuga and it is essentially that color all year in shade and sun.